# Stop debug mode in IntelliJ IDEA when using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I used a hint that said **use** `Run with --debug`, so I clicked on it. How can I remove the feature to get an output as usual?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clicking this link will create a new temporary configuration for Gradle that will have `--debug` argument added there:

[image: Debug arguments]

You can either remove this argument from the configuration or delete this configuration completely and continue using your existing run/debug configurations without this option.

More details can be found in [IntelliJ IDEA help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html).

Comment: It is actually saved at the tab "Run" -> "Edit Configurations..."

Answer (score 0):

Click the red square on the top right, like here: 
[image]

Alternatively you can also press it in the tab where you can control the debugger, which is on the down left:
[image]

If you don't see that, make sure to click on "Debug" on the bottom bar.

Comment: It was not saved there ![Picture](https://i.imgur.com/ITPbVc5.png)